# Button is "selected" when starting JavaFX program

Tags: java, button, javafx-8

When I run my JavaFX program, my first button is always kind of selected (see blue line around):  [picture form start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS4VJ.png)
When I use the arrow keys to set the player choices to left or right, the button left or right will be selected:
[after I pressed right arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxdug.png)
How can I run the program without any of the buttons selected

Comment: Can we see your scene creation code?

Answer (score 2):

just add `root.requestFocus()` after showing the stage

```
    public static void start(Stage stage)
    {
        try 
        {   FXMLLoader loader = new 
                FXMLLoader(StartMain.class.getResource("start.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            StartCompanion companion = loader.getController();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.setOnKeyPressed(companion::behandelSpeler);
            scene.setOnMouseClicked(companion::mouseClick);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            root.requestFocus();
       }
       catch (IOException ex)
       {
                MyError.show("Fout bij opstarten van applicatie");
       }
    }
```

Comment: thank you! that worked :D Can you explain what this does? I looked up in the library but it isn't that clear for me.

Comment: it just make the **focus** go to the `root` of the scene